# AttributeError: module 'firebase.firebase' has no attribute 'post' on firebase python

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, python-requests, python-3.6

I am trying to add data to my firebase real-time database. I am using this following code below:

```
from firebase import firebase

class Sugar:

    firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication('https://diatrack-48525.firebaseio.com/',authentication=None)
    result = firebase.post('/Sugar type',{'name':name,'gender':gender,'age': age,'sugartype':'Type 1'})
```

It shows following error:

```
result = firebase.post('/Sugar type',{'name':name,'gender':gender,'age': age,'sugartype':'Type 1'})
AttributeError: module 'firebase.firebase' has no attribute 'post'
```

Answer (score 6):

It's may be because you're in a class scope, and the duplicate `firebase` names (module & variable) aren't working properly. Does this work?

```
from firebase import firebase

class Sugar:

    firebase_app = firebase.FirebaseApplication('https://diatrack-48525.firebaseio.com/',authentication=None)
    result = firebase_app('/Sugar type',{'name':name,'gender':gender,'age': age,'sugartype':'Type 1'})
```

Comment: I tried to change the variable. It doesn't work also.